# Method getHardwareAddress() gives NullPointerException when using other network's ip

Tags: java, networking, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to print the Physical address of other computer connected to my network by their ip address.

Using `arp -a` I can see all networks and their physical address.

But when running a java code I can't retrieve the physical address of it's corresponding ip and it gives me a `NullPointerException` on the line invoking the `getHardwareAddress()` method. But If its my computer's ip it gives proper output and no exception is thrown.

Here is what I've got.

```
public void printMacAddress() throws UnknownHostException, SocketException {
    String ipAddress = "192.168.0.105";
    byte[] mac = null;
    InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(add);
    mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i],
                (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
    }
    System.out.print("The mac address is : ");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only get `NetworkInterface` objects for your own network interfaces, not those of other hosts. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html):

> It is used to identify the local interface

When you called `NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(add)` where `add` is a foreign IP address, it therefore returned `null,` which you didn't check for, and so you got a `NullPointerException` when you used it.

You can't do this.

Comment: If I can only use it for my own network interfaces, why does using 127.0.0.1 as ip gives me a blank output?

Comment: Because 127.0.0.1 isn't an Ethernet interface, so it doesn't have a MAC address.

Comment: How can I get my desired output if my posted method will not do?

Comment: If your 'desired output' is the MAC address of 127.0.0.1, you *can't* get it, because it doesn't exist. If it is the MAC address of a remote host, you will have to engage in an ARP protocol request. Why do you want these MAC addresses? There's nothing useful you can do with them in Java except display them.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can use MAC address as another layer of security for my program. Allowing only devices with a match on the list of valid MAC address to proceed to the next layer of security(example is login).

Comment: No. MAC addresses don't provide any security. They can be changed by the user, both within the same adpater and when changing adapters, and they aren't necessarily unique.

Comment: Ok, now it's useless I think. Is there any information unique for an individual PC?

Comment: You need to ask yourself whether there's any actual point in this, and whether you aren't trying to be counter-productive. A user is entitled to login to your system from any host of his own choosing surely? without having to call you every time he gets a new one? or a new disk? or a new NIC?